# Laravel adicionando código com CRSF_TOKEN no final da página

Tags: laravel, csrf

Eu conheço um pouco sobre como funciona o `@csrf_token` do Laravel, mas estou enfrentando um problema.

O código abaixo está sendo adicionado ao final de todas as minhas Views e isso acontece sem eu ter implementado nada. Outro detalhe é que só acontece se eu acesso a aplicação fora da mesma rede, por exemplo, a da minha casa. Se acesso da mesma rede o código não é adicionado.

Por favor alguém sabe me informar se isso é da minha aplicação? Pois estou usando Laravel e esse *token* não parece vir dele, pois não tem nada que implementa esse JavaScript nele.

**Código que é adicionado ao final de cada página**:

```
<html>
    <script language="JavaScript"> 
    var tokenName = 'CSRF_TOKEN'; 
    var tokenValue = 'dd0576475d5be8ed4dd7a7c3941d7168cadc8686'; 

    function updateTags() {         
        var all = document.all ? document.all : document.getElementsByTagName('*');         
        var len = all.length;         
        for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {                 
            var e = all[i];                                 
            updateTag(e, 'src');                 
            updateTag(e, 'href');         
        } 
    } 

    function updateForms() {         
        var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');                         
        for(i=0; i<forms.length; i++) {                 
            var html = forms[i].innerHTML;                                 
            html += '<input type=hidden name=' + tokenName + ' value=' + tokenValue + ' />';                 
            forms[i].innerHTML = html;         
        } 
    } 

    function updateTag(element, attr) {         
        var location = element.getAttribute(attr);         
        if(location != null && location != '' && isHttpLink(location)) {                 
            var index = location.indexOf('?');                 
            if(index != -1) {                         
                location = location + '&' + tokenName + '=' + tokenValue;                 
            } else {                         
                location = location + '?' + tokenName + '=' + tokenValue;                 
            }                
            element.setAttribute(attr, location);         
        } 
    } 

    function isHttpLink(src) {         
        var result = 0;                         
        if(src.substring(0, 4) != 'http' || src.substring(0, 1) == '/') {                 
            result = 1;         
        }                 

        return result; 
    } 

    updateTags(); 
    updateForms(); 
    </script>
</html>
```

Então eu estou usando a versão laravel mais recente 5.7.* e uso a tag de @csrf nos meus forms assim mesmo arroba csrf -> @csrf. Uso no header das paginas tambem

Comment: Pode manda como esta utilizando o @csrf na sua blade? Qual a versão do Laravel?

Comment: Add informações no final

Comment: Como você está aplicando no seu header? Assim: <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">?

Comment: sim exatamente conforme a doc

Comment: Já experimentou tirar do header, para ver se mesmo assim o código aparece?

Comment: Sim, ja fiz de um tudo! O mais estrando é que deixei uma view sem nada nenhum codigo e mesmo assim é injetado esse codigo JS na pagina e ta atrapalhando algumas coisas minhas ateé que se não atrapalhasse. Na doc do laravel não fala nada disso!

Comment: Eu acredito que o que esta ocorrendo não tem haver com o Laravel e sim com alguma biblioteca javascript que você possa estar utilizando em seu projeto.

Comment: Você está desenvolvendo o projeto desde o início, ou pegou um código fonte já existente?

Comment: Não faz sentido pq eu fiz um teste retirando todos os assets que chamam bibliotecas JS e tudo mais. E mesmo assim o codigo e como deixei a view limpa apenas ele aparece. Não tem quase nada Na internet a respeito.

Comment: Tente desabilitar o mod_security2 no apache para verificar se trecho de código some.